# How to setup `screen` command to run for every ssh session?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I'd like to record the activity for every ssh user connecting to my box. I think `screen` could help with it. I'm thinking on having `screen` running for every ssh user automatically upon ssh login and recording its activity to some file. Is that possible?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/362532/how-can-i-log-user-activity-on-ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OS allows it, consider to use byobu, see some arguments for the why here:
https://superuser.com/questions/423310/byobu-versus-gnu-screen-versus-tmux

Other options for logging user activities you'll find here: http://www.howtoforge.com/options-for-user-auditing-on-linux-platforms

Answer (score 1):

See also this program, that was designed to be used with sshd's ForceCommand: https://github.com/open-ch/log-user-session